# Dart get back value of function

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to learn Dart by my self, but I come from C and I a bit confused...

I'm doing this :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future <Map>    ft_get_data()
{
    File    data;

    data = new File("data.json");
    return data.exists().then((value) {
        if (!value)
        {
            print("Data does no exist...\nCreating file...");
            data.createSync();
            print("Filling it...");
            data.openWrite().write('{"index":{"content":"Helllo"}}');
            print("Operation finish");
        }
        return (1);
    }).then((value) {
        data.readAsString().then((content){
            return JSON.decode(content);
        }).catchError((e) {
            print("error");
            return (new Map());
        });
    });
}

void    main()
{
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080).then((server) {
        print("Server is lauching... $server");
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
            ft_get_data().then((data_map) {
                if (data_map && data_map.isNotEmpty)
                    request.response.write(data_map['index']['content']);
                else
                    request.response.write('Not work');
            }).whenComplete(request.response.close);
        });
    }) .catchError((error) {
        print("An error : $error.");
    });
}
```

I'm trying to get back the new Map, and as you can guess, it doesn't work and I get the 'Not work' msg. While when the code was in same function, it worked...

Please, could you help me ?

And, there a pointer system as C ?

```dart
void function(int *i)
{
    *i = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    function(&i);
    printf("%d", i);
}
// Output is 2.
```

Thank you for your help.

Final code :

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Map> ft_get_data()
{
    File    data;

    data = new File("data.json");
    return data.exists()
    .then((value) {
        if (!value) {
            print("Data does no exist...\nCreating file...");
            data.createSync();
            print("Filling it...");
            data.openWrite().write('{"index":{"content":"Helllo"}}');
            print("Operation finish");
        }
    })
    .then((_) => data.readAsString())
    .then((content) => JSON.decode(content))
    .catchError((e) => new Map());
}

void        main()
{
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    .then((server) {
        print("Server is lauching... $server");
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
            ft_get_data()
            .then((data_map) {
                if (data_map.isNotEmpty)
                    request.response.write(data_map['index']['content']);
                else
                    request.response.write('Not work');
            })
            .whenComplete(request.response.close);
        });
    })
    .catchError((error) {
        print("An error : $error.");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reconstruct your code to "readable" format. I haven't test it, so there might be errors. For me the code is much easier to read if `.then()` are not nested. Also it helps reading, if `.then()` starts a new line.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

Future <Map>ft_get_data()
{
    File data;

    data = new File("data.json");
    data.exists() //returns true or false
    .then((value) { // value is true or false
        if (!value) {
            print("Data does no exist...\nCreating file...");
            data.createSync();
            print("Filling it...");
            data.openWrite().write('{"index":{"content":"Helllo"}}');
            print("Operation finish");
        }
    }) // this doesn't need to return anything
    .then((_) => data.readAsString()) // '_' indicates that there is no input value, returns a string. This line can removed if you add return data.readAsString(); to the last line of previous function.
    .then((content) => JSON.decode(content)); // returns decoded string, this is the output of ft_get_data()-function
//    .catchError((e) { //I believe that these errors will show in main-function's error
//      print("error");
//    });
}

void    main()
{
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    .then((server) {
        print("Server is lauching... $server");
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
            ft_get_data()
            .then((data_map) {
                if (data_map && data_map.isNotEmpty)
                    request.response.write(data_map['index']['content']);
                else
                    request.response.write('Not work');
            })
            .whenComplete(request.response.close);
        });
    }) 
    .catchError((error) {
        print("An error : $error.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand the code (thank you for tips). But, I don't understand why it's still not working..

Comment: I think you should add `print` lines to each of `then`'s and see what is happening. If you have those prints and you use Dart Editor for coding, you can add debugger breakpoints to each of prints and then run program step by step and in each breakpoints examine values of variables. If you can tell exactly what is not working, it'll be possible to help more.

Comment: I tried with Dart 1.2, it's working, I got 1.3 and for unknown reason, it doesn't work... I have just add a "return" before "data.exists()" and uncomment catchError

Comment: Glad you solved the issue, but difference between dart versions and your solution is ??? This is why we love programming :)

Answer (score 1):

After a brief look I would say you need

```dart
Future<Map> ft_get_data() {
  ...
  return data.exists() ...
  ...
}
```

and use it like

```dart
server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
  request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED;
  ft_get_data().then((data_map) {
    if (data_map && data_map.isNotEmpty) request.response.write(
        data_map['index']['content']); 
    else 
        request.response.write('Not work');
    request.response.close();
  });
});
```

A `return` inside a `then` doesn't return from `ft_get_data` but only from `then`
If an async call is involved you can't continue if it was sync, it's then async all the way down.

Comment: Thank you, I have add "Map data_map" and replace return by a simple affectation as "data_map = new Map();". And place only one return at end of the function "return data_map"... And, i'm lost...

Comment: That doesn't work. If you call an async function like `data.Exists()` this call just gets registered in the queue, then the next statement is the function is executed (if any) or the function returns. When there is nothing else executing the next call registered in the queue gets executed. Keep your function as it is in your question just change  the return type (like in my answer) and write a return in front of `data.exists()`

Comment: I read this, it help me a lot before a ask. But even with your suggestion, it's not working... I have edit my first code

Comment: Your updated code looks good so far after a brief look. What do you mean by `it's not working`? Do you get an error/warning in DartEditor or when you execute it, or no result, ...?

Comment: No warning, but it doesn't display the expected information. It supposed to show me the inner of my json. When I do a print of my data_map, he is empty... i think that i don't get the returned map of my function.

Comment: I'll take a look again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot insert one then() into the other. Need to chain them. Otherwise, return JSON.decode(data) returns to nowhere (main event loop) instead of previous "then" handler